# How to use regexp with linux expect?

Tags: shell, expect, alpine-linux, duplicity-backup

I want to use Duplicity to backup my files from shell, but it requires the password to be passed twice before run. I thought of expect to solve the problem, but I cannot make it work.
What I tried:

```
expect "Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.\nLast full backup date: none\nLast full backup is too old, forcing full backup\nGnuPG passphrase for decryption: " {send "$pass\r"}
expect "Retype passphrase for decryption to confirm: " {send "$pass\r"}
```

There is a multi line message from Duplicity. I tried `expect -re` to use regexp, but it did not recognize the r option.
I use Alpine in a docker container.

Comment: [pure speculation] Usually those happens because busy box's commands are trimmed down [/pure speculation], which might be your issue here

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking: When you type `expect` here, is this the **expect**- command `expect`, or is it the **shell**-command expect? It would make more sense if you would post your whole expect script, and also that part of your shell script which runs the expect script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first pattern is not matching because Expect uses `\r\n` for all newlines.

Run your code with `expect -f script.exp` for verbose output to see how expect is attempting to match.

You could write

```
expect "Local and Remote metadata*GnuPG passphrase for decryption: " {send "$pass\r"}
```

By default, the `expect` command uses glob-matching like the tcl [`string match`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35) commabnd